# WPF text overlay grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've searched whole stackoverflow and can't find simple solution to solve my problem.

I have grid and I want to overlay whole grid by some text/image. Do you have any ideas how can I do it?

Actually it is tetris game and I would like to show user text/image "Game Over" after he lose, so I need to do it manually from c#. Any ideas ?

Thanks for any help :-)

```
<Window x:Class="TetrisWPF.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TetrisWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
     AllowsTransparency="True" 
  ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
  WindowStyle="None"
  ShowInTaskbar="True"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    KeyDown="HandleKeyDown"
    Initialized="MainWindow_Initilized" Background="#222222">
<Window.Resources>

    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome</FontFamily>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="false">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Visibility="Hidden" Width="300">Right</Button>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="311" >
        <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Click="btnPlay_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/>
        <Label Content="Score " Height="56" x:Name="Score" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Lines " Height="56" x:Name="Lines" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Level 1" Height="56" x:Name="level" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        <Button  x:Name="buttonPlay" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonPlay_Click" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Image Name="img1" Source="C:\Users\xx\Pictures\btn.png" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="buttonPause" Content="Pause (L1)" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonPause_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonRestart" Content="Restart" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonRestart_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonStop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonStop_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonDemo" Content="Demo" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonDemo_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonExit" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="205" Click="buttonExit_Click"  />
        <TextBlock x:Name="GameOverText" Height="56" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Game Over" Foreground="#FFD41A1A"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="GamePausedText" Height="56" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Game Paused" Foreground="#FF0D15B6" Margin="0,0,-0.8,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Height="750" Width="375" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a grid, you can simply add objects occupying the same space and they will overlap in the order you've added them. With your example, you've got a lot of columns and rows, so to overlay something over all of them you'd have to set it's RowSpan and ColumnSpan to the number of rows/columns you have for it to fill all the space.

An easier way might be to put your grid in another grid (with only 1 row and column), and add something to that (this is what I do when I want to overlay components, just stick them in their own little 1x1 grid).

Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid" Height="750" Width="375" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        ... all those columns
    </Grid>
    <Border Name="GameOverlay" Background="Black" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Text="Game Over!" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"
                   FontSize="24"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Note, it's important to set a background to something if you want to obscure your original content (though a half-transparent background might look cool!).

To show and hide it in the code, simply show & hide it with `GameOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` or `GameOverlay.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden`, or bind this to a property that you can change.

This way you can make it look how you want, place it where you want, with it set to Visible in the designer, then change it to Hidden (so you can make it visible in the code).

Much easier than constructing it in code when you need it and manually adding it to the UX.

Comment: Thanks ! You save my day, really :-) I was trying something similar but I don't know why it didn't work. Your soulution is great !

Comment: No problem. Were you trying to add it to the game grid, and then adding your game elements in code? This would result in the order being all messed up (they're drawn in the order you add them). You can force the draw order using Canvas.ZIndex. Easier just shoving it higher up in the tree in it's own grid! Also, it's usually more efficient to make things hidden and show them when needed if it's changing fast.